# Server.UrlEncode in .ashx

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

I would like to use `Server.UrlEncode` in `.ashx`.

I try with the following code.

```
HttpServerUtility ser = new HttpServerUtility();
ser.UrlEncode(pfile.FileName);
```

That's wrong but however I would like to use Server.UrlEncode so let know the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode

... or you can use the methods of Uri such as [EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) which I tend to prefer because of the fact that they can be used even outside of ASP.NET.